# Shiny app very slow and RegData error, what in code might be causing this?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to run a dashboard on shiny and the end result is incredibly slow, I'm also getting an error when running so i suspect the app might have crashed? any idea what in the code might be causing this?

I just start to code the linear regression I'm not sure about the efficiently of the code.

The plots not appears on the dashboard.

Thank youu

```
    # Define UI ----
    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("AirBnb NYC"),
      sidebarLayout(  
      sidebarPanel( 
      
          fluidRow(
             column(3,
                   selectInput("select", h3("Which Neighbourhood group ?"), choices = 
    c("Brooklyn","Manhattan","Queens","Staten Island", "Bronx"))),
            column(3,
                   selectInput("select2", h3("which Neighbourhood ?"), choices = "")),
            column(3,
                   selectInput("select1", h3("Room Type"), choices = ""))),
          p("Select the inputs for the Dependent Variable"),
          selectInput(inputId = "DepVar", label = "Dependent Variables", multiple = FALSE, choices = 
    colnames(AB_NYC_2019)),
          p("Select the inputs for the Independent Variable"),
          selectInput(inputId = "IndVar", label = "Independent Variables", multiple = FALSE, 
                  choices = list( "price"))
    ),
      


      mainPanel( leafletOutput("map",width = "100%",height = "800"), 
                 fluidRow(column(width = 6, plotOutput("data")),
                          column(width = 6, plotOutput("plot"))),
                 verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "RegSum"),
                 verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "IndPrint"),
                 verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "DepPrint"))
    ))
```

## Define server logic ----

```
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
      #Define parameters of search  
      observe({
        print(input$select)
        x <- AB_NYC_2019 %>% filter(neighbourhood_group == input$select) %>% select(neighbourhood)
      updateSelectInput(session, "select2", "select your neighbourhood", choice = unique(x))
  })
  
      observe({
        productdata <- AB_NYC_2019$room_type[AB_NYC_2019$neighbourhood == input$select2]
        updateSelectInput(session, "select1", "Which room type?", choices = unique(productdata))
    })
  
  

  #Create map
      color <- colorFactor(palette = c("red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow"), 
    AB_NYC_2019$neighbourhood_group)
  
      filteredData <- reactive({filter(AB_NYC_2019, neighbourhood_group == input$select)})
                           
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
          map <- leaflet(filteredData()) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>%
     # setView(lng = -73.98928, lat = 40.75042, zoom = 10)  %>%
          addCircleMarkers(
            lng=~longitude, # Longitude coordinates
            lat=~latitude, # Latitude coordinates
            stroke=TRUE, # Circle stroke
            weight = 0.1,
            radius = 0.5,
            fillOpacity=0.5,
           color=~color(neighbourhood_group),
           label = paste("Name:", AB_NYC_2019$name, "<br>",
                      "Price:", AB_NYC_2019$price, "<br>",
                      "Reviews:", AB_NYC_2019$number_of_reviews, "<br>")) %>% 
               addLegend("bottomright", pal = color, values = ~neighbourhood_group,
                  title = "Neighbourhood groups",
                  opacity = 1
        )
      
  })
  
  #filter map
      observe({
        leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
        clearShapes() %>%
        addMarkers(~longitude, ~latitude, 
                     label = ~neighbourhood_group, 
                     labelOptions = labelOptions(textsize = "12px"))
  })
  
       lm1 <- reactive({lm(reformulate(input$IndVar, input$DepVar), data = RegData)})
       output$DepPrint <- renderPrint({input$DepVar})
       output$IndPrint <- renderPrint({input$IndVar})
       output$RegSum <- renderPrint({summary(lm1())})
  
       #Get many plots 
       output$data <- renderPlot({ 
       ggplot(AB_NYC_2019, aes(price)) +
       geom_histogram(bins = 30, aes(y = ..density..), fill = "purple") + 
       geom_density(alpha = 0.2, fill = "purple") +
       th +
       ggtitle("Distribution of price",
              subtitle = "The distribution is very skewed") +
       theme(axis.title = element_text(), axis.title.x = element_text()) +
       geom_vline(xintercept = round(mean(AB_NYC_2019$price), 2), size = 2, linetype = 3)
  })
  
       output$plot <- renderPlot({
         AB_NYC_2019 %>% filter(price >= mean(price)) %>% group_by(neighbourhood_group, room_type) %>% 
         tally %>% 
         ggplot(aes(reorder(neighbourhood_group,desc(n)), n, fill = room_type)) +
         th +
         xlab(NULL) +
         ylab("Number of objects") +
         ggtitle("Number of above average price objects",
              subtitle = "Most of them are entire homes or apartments") +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })

}
```

## Run the app ----

```
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In the plots you are using `th`.  I am not sure what that is.  Perhaps you meant `theme_bw()`.  Also, it may be best to run your code with only 50 observations in your dataframe, as it is too slow to add thousands of markers.

Comment: Once you replace `RegData` with `filteredData()`, `th` with `theme_bw()` in plots, and use `req()`, where necessary, your plots work fine.  To test it, please use top 50 or 100 rows from your dataframe.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is the function req() when it can be necessary ?

Comment: For more info on `req()`, please see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/req.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
AB_NYC_2019 <- AB_NYC_2019[1:50,]

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("AirBnb NYC"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", h3("Which Neighbourhood group ?"), choices =
                    c("Brooklyn","Manhattan","Queens","Staten Island", "Bronx")),
      selectInput("select2", h3("which Neighbourhood ?"), choices = ""),
      selectInput("select1", h3("Room Type"), choices = ""),

      p("Select the inputs for the Dependent Variable"),
      selectInput(inputId = "DepVar", label = "Dependent Variables", multiple = FALSE, choices =
                    colnames(AB_NYC_2019)),
      p("Select the inputs for the Independent Variable"),
      selectInput(inputId = "IndVar", label = "Independent Variables", multiple = FALSE,
                  choices = list( "price"))
    ),

    mainPanel( leafletOutput("map",width = "100%",height = "800"),
               fluidRow(column(width = 6, plotOutput("data")),
                        column(width = 6, plotOutput("plot"))),
               verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "RegSum"),
               verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "IndPrint"),
               verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "DepPrint"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Define parameters of search
  observe({
    req(input$select)
    x <- AB_NYC_2019 %>% dplyr::filter(neighbourhood_group == input$select) %>% select(neighbourhood)
    updateSelectInput(session, "select2", "select your neighbourhood", choice = unique(x))
  })

  observe({
    req(input$select2)
    productdata <- AB_NYC_2019$room_type[AB_NYC_2019$neighbourhood == input$select2]
    updateSelectInput(session, "select1", "Which room type?", choices = unique(productdata))
  })



  #Create map
  color <- colorFactor(palette = c("red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow"),
                       unique(AB_NYC_2019$neighbourhood_group))

  filteredData <- reactive({
    req(input$select)
    filter(AB_NYC_2019, neighbourhood_group == input$select)})

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    req(filteredData())
    map <- leaflet(filteredData()) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>%
      setView(lng = -73.98928, lat = 40.75042, zoom = 10)  %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        lng=~longitude, # Longitude coordinates
        lat=~latitude, # Latitude coordinates
        stroke=TRUE, # Circle stroke
        weight = 0.1,
        radius = 0.5,
        fillOpacity=0.5,
        color=~color(neighbourhood_group),
        label = paste("Name:", filteredData()$name, 
                      "\nPrice:", filteredData()$price, 
                      "\nReviews:", filteredData()$number_of_reviews)
        ) %>%
      addLegend("bottomright", pal = color, values = ~neighbourhood_group,
                title = "Neighbourhood groups",
                opacity = 1
      )

  })

  #filter map
  observe({
    req(filteredData())
    
    labs <- lapply(seq(nrow(filteredData())), function(i) {
      paste0( '<p> Name: ', filteredData()[i, "name"], '<p></p>', 'Price: ', 
              filteredData()[i, "price"],'</p><p>', 'Reviews: ',
              filteredData()[i, "number_of_reviews"], '</p>' ) 
    })
    
    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addMarkers(~longitude, ~latitude,
                 label = lapply(labs, htmltools::HTML),
                 labelOptions = labelOptions(textsize = "12px"))
  })

  lm1 <- reactive({
    req(filteredData())
    lm(reformulate(input$IndVar, input$DepVar), data = filteredData())})
  output$DepPrint <- renderPrint({input$DepVar})
  output$IndPrint <- renderPrint({input$IndVar})
  output$RegSum <- renderPrint({
    req(lm1())
    summary(lm1())})

  #Get many plots
  output$data <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(AB_NYC_2019, aes(price)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = 30, aes(y = ..density..), fill = "purple") +
      geom_density(alpha = 0.2, fill = "purple") +
      theme_bw() +
      ggtitle("Distribution of price",
              subtitle = "The distribution is very skewed") +
      theme(axis.title = element_text(), axis.title.x = element_text()) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = round(mean(AB_NYC_2019$price), 2), size = 2, linetype = 3)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    AB_NYC_2019 %>% filter(price >= mean(price)) %>% group_by(neighbourhood_group, room_type) %>%
      tally %>%
      ggplot(aes(reorder(neighbourhood_group,desc(n)), n, fill = room_type)) +
      theme_bw() +
      xlab(NULL) +
      ylab("Number of objects") +
      ggtitle("Number of above average price objects",
              subtitle = "Most of them are entire homes or apartments") +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This line doesn't work now   : label = paste("Name:", AB_NYC_2019$name, "<br>",
                      "Price:", AB_NYC_2019$price, "<br>",
                      "Reviews:", AB_NYC_2019$number_of_reviews, "<br>")) Do you know why ? And it's look like the map filter doesn't work too

Comment: You need to use the variables from `filteredData()` and not from `AB_NYC_2019` in the label.  Please see the updated code.

Comment: Fixed the labels to appear on multi-lines.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to make an interactive regression it doesn't work as I did